# displaying records from mysql in ul and li format with php

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

i want to display the mysql's fetched results with php and html in unordered list and list format  as like http://www.miniclip.com/games/en/. you can see in the all games categories in the footer in alphabetical order. the same requirement i do have. i guess i have written the logic its working fine. but i am unable to represent it properly. you can see in the following link above the footer. http://www.playtoongames.com/play1...

code:

```
<?php
$gameQuery = mysql_query ("SELECT name, LEFT(name, 1) AS first_char FROM games WHERE UPPER(name) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' OR name BETWEEN '0' AND '9' ORDER BY name");
$current_char = '';
   while ($gameRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($gameQuery)){
     if ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'fr'){
         $description = $gameRow['description_fr'];
     }else{
   $description = $gameRow['description'];
 }
?>

<div style='float:left' title="<img src='<?php echo $gameRow['sitePath'];?>games/images/<?php echo $gameRow['img_100x75'];?>' width='230' height='112' class='thumb' alt='<?php echo $gameRow['name'];?>'/>" class='tooltip'>

                     <ul>
                     <li>
     <a href='<?php echo $gameRow['sitePath'];?>play/<?php echo str_replace(' ','_',$gameRow['name']);?>'><?php echo $gameRow['name'];?></a>
                     </li> 
                      </ul>
</div>
```

can anybody look into this...

Regards,
sam.

Comment: use `firebug` to check css, following css is applied to ul `.fullgameslist .catGamesLists .categoryColumn {
    background: url("http://www.miniclip.com/images/bg_catlist_154.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2px;
    width: 154px;
}
css.ph...c=17921 (line 2)
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think the key is that there are 6 columns, which just means you'll need to break your array into 6 different parts.

Here's some psuedocode:

```
$pArr = $from_sql_array; // I'll let you take care of that.
$itmCount = count($pArr);
$itmsPerCol = ceil($itmCount / 6.0);
for ($ii=0; $ii < 6; $ii++)
{
  $pCol = array_slice($pArr, $itmsPerCol * $ii, $itmsPerCol);
  echo '<ul class="floatleft"><li>'.implode("</li>\n<li>",$pCol).'</li></ul>';
}
```

Comment: i have tried your code but its showing the following errors..Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\games\alphabets.php on line 39

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\games\alphabets.php on line 40

Comment: As I mention, this is pseudocode.  In reality, you'd loop through your SQL statements and build an array of objects.  That would be what you would assign to $pArr, outside of the mysql population loop.

Answer (score 3):

On the Playtoons site, each `<li>` is in its' own individual `<ul>` - this means you're creating a new list for each item:

```
<ul>
  <li>13 More Days</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>A Bikers Heaven</li>
</ul>
```

What you should be doing is using one `<ul>` which contains all the items as `<li>`s:

```
<ul>
  <li>13 More Days</li>
  <li>A Bikers Heaven</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi what, thanks for your response. please see my code. <ul>
                     <li>
     <a href='<?php echo $gameRow['sitePath'];?>play/<?php echo str_replace(' ','_',$gameRow['name']);?>'><?php echo $gameRow['name'];?></a>
                     </li> 
                      </ul>

Comment: @phphunger I imagine you're looping through the database in PHP - make sure that the <ul> tags are outside of the loop. Eg <ul> <?php foreach ... etc

Comment: i tried outside the loop also the result is some what different but not what i want. i have posted my entire code in my original post. you can see this...